# Production build for Django web app raising SuspiciousFileOperation when accessed

Tags: python, django, deployment, django-settings

I am attempting to make a production build for my application however I am getting an error I do not really understand. The application runs, however an internal server error occurs every time it is accessed from localhost in a browser. This is the stack trace:

```
[2017-09-01 17:34:07 +0100] [5301] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
[2017-09-01 17:34:07 +0100] [5301] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (5301)
[2017-09-01 17:34:07 +0100] [5301] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2017-09-01 17:34:07 +0100] [5304] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 5304
[2017-09-01 16:34:16 +0000] [5304] [ERROR] Error handling request /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/callum/Documents/Tutoring/Tutoring/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 135, in handle
    self.handle_request(listener, req, client, addr)
  File "/Users/callum/Documents/Tutoring/Tutoring/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 176, in handle_request
    respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
  File "/Users/callum/Documents/Tutoring/Tutoring/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/whitenoise/base.py", line 66, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/callum/Documents/Tutoring/Tutoring/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 170, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/Users/callum/Documents/Tutoring/Tutoring/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in get_response
    response = self._middleware_chain(request)
  File "/Users/callum/Documents/Tutoring/Tutoring/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 44, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "/Users/callum/Documents/Tutoring/Tutoring/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 86, in response_for_exception
    response = get_exception_response(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), 400, exc)
  File "/Users/callum/Documents/Tutoring/Tutoring/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 116, in get_exception_response
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
  File "/Users/callum/Documents/Tutoring/Tutoring/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 143, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return callback(request, **param_dict)
  File "/Users/callum/Documents/Tutoring/Tutoring/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 149, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/callum/Documents/Tutoring/Tutoring/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/defaults.py", line 74, in server_error
    return http.HttpResponseServerError(template.render())
  File "/Users/callum/Documents/Tutoring/Tutoring/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 66, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/Users/callum/Documents/Tutoring/Tutoring/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 208, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/Users/callum/Documents/Tutoring/Tutoring/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 199, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/callum/Documents/Tutoring/Tutoring/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 994, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/callum/Documents/Tutoring/Tutoring/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/callum/Documents/Tutoring/Tutoring/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 174, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/Users/callum/Documents/Tutoring/Tutoring/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 199, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/callum/Documents/Tutoring/Tutoring/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 994, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/callum/Documents/Tutoring/Tutoring/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/callum/Documents/Tutoring/Tutoring/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/templatetags/static.py", line 104, in render
    url = self.url(context)
  File "/Users/callum/Documents/Tutoring/Tutoring/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/templatetags/static.py", line 101, in url
    return self.handle_simple(path)
  File "/Users/callum/Documents/Tutoring/Tutoring/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/templatetags/static.py", line 114, in handle_simple
    return staticfiles_storage.url(path)
  File "/Users/callum/Documents/Tutoring/Tutoring/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 132, in url
    hashed_name = self.stored_name(clean_name)
  File "/Users/callum/Documents/Tutoring/Tutoring/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 292, in stored_name
    cache_name = self.clean_name(self.hashed_name(name))
  File "/Users/callum/Documents/Tutoring/Tutoring/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 93, in hashed_name
    if not self.exists(clean_name):
  File "/Users/callum/Documents/Tutoring/Tutoring/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 394, in exists
    return os.path.exists(self.path(name))
  File "/Users/callum/Documents/Tutoring/Tutoring/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 52, in path
    return super(StaticFilesStorage, self).path(name)
  File "/Users/callum/Documents/Tutoring/Tutoring/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 407, in path
    return safe_join(self.location, name)
  File "/Users/callum/Documents/Tutoring/Tutoring/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/_os.py", line 78, in safe_join
    'component ({})'.format(final_path, base_path))
SuspiciousFileOperation: The joined path (/js/jquery.js) is located outside of the base path component (/Users/callum/Documents/Tutoring/Tutoring/staticfiles)
[2017-09-01 16:34:17 +0000] [5304] [ERROR] Error handling request /favicon.ico
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/callum/Documents/Tutoring/Tutoring/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 135, in handle
    self.handle_request(listener, req, client, addr)
  File "/Users/callum/Documents/Tutoring/Tutoring/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 176, in handle_request
    respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
  File "/Users/callum/Documents/Tutoring/Tutoring/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/whitenoise/base.py", line 66, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/callum/Documents/Tutoring/Tutoring/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 170, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/Users/callum/Documents/Tutoring/Tutoring/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in get_response
    response = self._middleware_chain(request)
  File "/Users/callum/Documents/Tutoring/Tutoring/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 44, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "/Users/callum/Documents/Tutoring/Tutoring/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 86, in response_for_exception
    response = get_exception_response(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), 400, exc)
  File "/Users/callum/Documents/Tutoring/Tutoring/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 116, in get_exception_response
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
  File "/Users/callum/Documents/Tutoring/Tutoring/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 143, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return callback(request, **param_dict)
  File "/Users/callum/Documents/Tutoring/Tutoring/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 149, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/callum/Documents/Tutoring/Tutoring/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/defaults.py", line 74, in server_error
    return http.HttpResponseServerError(template.render())
  File "/Users/callum/Documents/Tutoring/Tutoring/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 66, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/Users/callum/Documents/Tutoring/Tutoring/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 208, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/Users/callum/Documents/Tutoring/Tutoring/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 199, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/callum/Documents/Tutoring/Tutoring/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 994, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/callum/Documents/Tutoring/Tutoring/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/callum/Documents/Tutoring/Tutoring/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 174, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/Users/callum/Documents/Tutoring/Tutoring/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 199, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/callum/Documents/Tutoring/Tutoring/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 994, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/callum/Documents/Tutoring/Tutoring/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/callum/Documents/Tutoring/Tutoring/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/templatetags/static.py", line 104, in render
    url = self.url(context)
  File "/Users/callum/Documents/Tutoring/Tutoring/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/templatetags/static.py", line 101, in url
    return self.handle_simple(path)
  File "/Users/callum/Documents/Tutoring/Tutoring/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/templatetags/static.py", line 114, in handle_simple
    return staticfiles_storage.url(path)
  File "/Users/callum/Documents/Tutoring/Tutoring/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 132, in url
    hashed_name = self.stored_name(clean_name)
  File "/Users/callum/Documents/Tutoring/Tutoring/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 292, in stored_name
    cache_name = self.clean_name(self.hashed_name(name))
  File "/Users/callum/Documents/Tutoring/Tutoring/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 93, in hashed_name
    if not self.exists(clean_name):
  File "/Users/callum/Documents/Tutoring/Tutoring/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 394, in exists
    return os.path.exists(self.path(name))
  File "/Users/callum/Documents/Tutoring/Tutoring/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 52, in path
    return super(StaticFilesStorage, self).path(name)
  File "/Users/callum/Documents/Tutoring/Tutoring/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 407, in path
    return safe_join(self.location, name)
  File "/Users/callum/Documents/Tutoring/Tutoring/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/_os.py", line 78, in safe_join
    'component ({})'.format(final_path, base_path))
SuspiciousFileOperation: The joined path (/js/jquery.js) is located outside of the base path component (/Users/callum/Documents/Tutoring/Tutoring/staticfiles)
```

I have created a settings_production.py by following the hellowebapp book available online:

```
# Inherit from standard settings file for defaults
from tutoring.settings import *

# Everything below will override our standard settings:

# Parse database configuration from $DATABASE_URL
import dj_database_url
DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config()

# Honor the 'X-Forwarded-Proto' header for request.is_secure()
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

# Allow all host headers
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

# Set debug to False
DEBUG = False

# Static asset configuration
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

I am very confused for why this error is occurring, it seems to have a problem with my jquery file which is in my apps directory. Please request more information if needed to help me find why this error present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like somewhere in one of your templates you have:

```
{% static '/js/jquery.js' %}
```

This should be changed to:

```
{% static 'js/jquery.js' %}
```

You can't pass absolute paths to the `static` tag (though I agree that the resulting error is not very clear!)

Comment: Worked perfect thank you! However my next error as cropped up to do with loading static files and i'm in a similar position again.